# Convert YAML array to Bash array

Tags: ruby, bash, yaml

I've an **YAML** array:

```
myarray:
    - PHP
    - Perl
    - Python
```

How to convert it into bash array with **ruby** ?

```
Arr[0]='PHP'
Arr[1]='Perl'
Arr[2]='Python'
```

Comment: What do you mean `convert it into bash array`? What are you actually trying to do?

Comment: I want to create a config.sh from an yaml file for a vagrant box...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is what you want.

In ruby, parse the yaml array and write an output for Bash to read as an array:

```
require 'yaml'

yaml_array = <<-eos
myarray:
    - PHP
    - Perl
    - Python
eos

yaml = YAML.load(yaml_array)
print "(#{yaml["myarray"].join(' ')})"
```

This ruby script will print `(PHP Perl Python)` to stdout.

You can then use it in Bash:

```
$ eval array=$(ruby ruby_script.rb)
$ echo ${array[0]}
PHP
$ echo ${array[1]}
Perl
```

Comment: Great ! It's as I want. Thanks a lot

Comment: This will be safer for the shell side: `print "(\"#{yaml["myarray"].join('" "')}\")"` -- contain any element that contains whitespace

Answer (score 2):

```
require 'yaml'

yaml_text = "myarray:
    - PHP
    - Perl
    - Python"

yaml = YAML.load(yaml_text)
array = yaml["myarray"]

puts array.class #=> Array
puts array       #=> PHP
                 #=> Perl
                 #=> Python
```

Answer (score 2):

The bash `mapfile` command is useful to convert lines of stdin into an array:

```
$ cat file.yaml 
myarray:
    - PHP
    - Perl
    - Python
    - element with spaces

$ mapfile -t array < <(ruby -ryaml -e 'yaml = YAML.load(File.read(ARGV.shift)); puts yaml["myarray"].join("\n")' file.yaml)

$ for i in "${!array[@]}"; do echo "$i  ${array[i]}"; done
0  PHP
1  Perl
2  Python
3  element with spaces
```

This avoids having to use `eval` in the shell

Comment: NIce function indeed but only avail in bash 4+ which I do not have unfortunately (just to warn others)